# Suites not seem to be executing nested suits

Tags: scalatest

I have created a `Suite` with nested suites. I suppose this will run tests sequentially in order- http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/Suites.html

```
class RepositoryTestController extends Suites {
  new AnswersRepositorySpecs
  new AnswersTransactionRepositorySpecs
  new CassandraRepositorySpecs
  new PartitionsOfATagRepositorySpecs
  new PasswordRepositorySpecs
  new PracticeQuestionsRepositorySpecs
  new PracticeQuestionsTagsRepositorySpecs
  new QuestionsAnsweredByAUserForATagSpecs
  new QuestionsCreatedByAUserForATagSpecs
  new SupportedTagsRepositorySpecs
  new UserProfileAndPortfolioRepositorySpecs
  new UsersRepositorySpecs
  new UserTokenRepositorySpecs
}
```

When I run these tests (by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+F10` in `IntelliJ`), I see prompt `Tests Passed 0`.

UPDATE
I suppose the problem could be that I haven't created a `PlaySpec`. I have not created this class (partially) as I don't know how to go about creating `Args` required by `run` method.

```
class RepositorySpecs extends PlaySpec {
  "Repository Specs" should {
    "run all specs" in {
      val specs = new RepositoryTestController()
      specs.run(None) //run requires Args which I am unable to create. http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/Suites.html
    }
  }
```

It seems the tests are not getting executed. How do I run the tests?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=SCL with the sample project attached and the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. It seems it is not IntelliJ issue but the way I am using Scalatest.